# Sumif rows and drag down to increment column (index - match)

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet with rows for tasks and columns for staff. I am trying to sum the total for each staff for each section of tasks on a different sheet.

Here is what my data looks like:

```
Task#   Role 1  Role 2  Role 3
1           
1.005   1       3       2
1.01    2       2       4
2           
2.001   1       3       4
2.03    6       1       3
```

And my expected output looks like this:

```
Role    Task 1  Task 2
Role 1  3       7
Role 2  5       4
Role 3  6       7
```

I have a formula that is working but I had to hard-code in the row numbers for each group of tasks:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Matrix!$12:$36,0,ROW(1:1)-1+16))
```

In my formula, Matrix!$12:$36 are the rows that correspond to the first group of tasks and ROW(1:1) is role 1. So, when I drag the formula down it returns the sum for each role for that section of tasks.

But, I realized that in some old versions of the workbook, there were different numbers of tasks for each section so I think I need to make it a SUMIF based on the task number.

I did see a couple of similar questions but I'm not familiar enough with index formulas to get it to work. Appreciate any tips on how to adjust my formula to incorporate a sumif, or other ideas to accomplish this.

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with full columns and does not matter how many per:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($B:$D,0,MATCH($F2,$B$1:$D$1,0)),$A:$A,">="&COLUMN(A:A),$A:$A,"<"&COLUMN(B:B))
```

[image]

Comment: The `COLUMN(A:A)` and `COLUMN(B:B)` are just counters.  So in the first column it is saying return everything that is `>=1` AND `<2`.  then when the formula gets copied/dragged to the next column the reference changes and now it is looking for `>=2` and `<3` and so on.  so it should go column by column updating the search range.  It should work for 1 to over 16,000.  Do not change those references in the `COLUMNS` they need to start in A and B regardless where the data is, they do not actually refer to the data but a merely counters.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to understand the second part of your formula: 

$A:$A,">="&COLUMN(A:A),$A:$A,"<"&COLUMN(B:B)

are you comparing the value in the cell to the value above/below it? 

For example, in G3, it checks if A3 is greater than A2 and less than A4? Something like that?

Comment: no as stated, above, `COLUMN(A:A)` and `COLUMN(B:B)` do not refer to values in the data set but return the column number itself `1` and `2` respectively in this case.  The when it copies over it becomes `COLUMN(B:B)` and `COLUMN(C:C)` or `2` and `3` Respectively.  it has nothing to do with the values in those columns.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining. I appreciate your help with this!